# from mysqli to PDO not fetching everything

Tags: php, sql, json, pdo, mysqli

Hey There I'm trying to change my php sql query code from mysqli to PDO, because I could inject it myself.
The mysqli code is looking l

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
     $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);`
```

The PDO code like this

```
$statement=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
```

This is the query:

```
Select s.*, t.team_name as team_1_name, t1.team_name as team_2_name from spiele s, 
   teams t, teams t1, gruppen g, kategorien k where s.team_1=t.team_id and
   t.gruppen_id=g.gruppen_id and g.kategorien_id=k.kategorien_id and k.kat_name='".$kat."'
   and s.team_2=t1.team_id
Union Select s.*, t.team_name as team_1_name, t1.team_name as team_2_name from
   gruppenfinalspiele s, gruppenfinalteams t1, gruppenfinalteams t, gruppen g, kategorien k
   where s.team_1=t.finalteam_id and t.gruppen_id=g.gruppen_id and
   g.kategorien_id=k.kategorien_id and k.kat_name='".$kat."' and s.team_2=t1.finalteam_id
Union Select s.*, t.team_name as team_1_name, t1.team_name as team_2_name from
   halbfinalspiele s, halbfinalteams t, halbfinalteams t1, kategorien k where
   s.team_1=t.finalteam_id and t.kategorien_id=k.kategorien_id and k.kat_name='".$kat."'
   and s.team_2=t1.finalteam_id
Union Select s.finalspiel_id, s.team_1, s.team_2, s.spielzeit, s.feld, s.tore_1, s.tore_2, 
   s.sieger, s.placeholder_team_1 as team_1_name, s.placeholder_team_2 as team_2_name from 
   finalspiele s, kategorien k where s.kategorien_id=k.kategorien_id and 
   k.kat_name='".$kat."'
ORDER BY spielzeit, Feld
```

And these are the first rows of results:
for mysqli:

```
[{"spiel_id":"2","team_1":"1","team_2":"2","spielzeit":"18:00:00","feld":"A",
 "tore_1":"0","tore_2":"4","sieger":"2","team_1_name":"Los Ventilos Oberdorf", 
 "team_2_name":"Sambaschr\u00e4nzer Bubendorf 2"},
```

and for PDO:

```
{"spiel_id":"2","team_1":"1","team_2":"2","spielzeit":"18:00:00","feld":"A",
 "tore_1":"0","tore_2":"4","sieger":"2","team_1_name":"Los Ventilos Oberdorf",
 "team_2_name":null}
```

now the problem is that the last Value (team_2_name) is null. Does someone can tell my why or what do I have to change?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: I've edited it to my question

Comment: My guess is that something in PDO isn't interpreting this portion of the data `\u00e4` because it is a unicode char. Can you edit this registry and take it out from this string just to test?

Comment: Thank you very much this was the problem. I forget to set it to utf8. To set it i just added:  $pdo->exec("set names utf8");